# Error en envío de mensajes sockets java

Tags: java, consola, socket, mensajes

Bueno tengo un programa de Cliente-servidor el cual envía mensajes.El cliente escribe un mensaje pero el servidor no despliega el mensaje que yo escribí, alguien me podría explicar el por qué.

Este es el cliente :

```
package pracsocket1;

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Cliente();
    }

    static final String HOST = "localhost";
    static final int PUERTO = 5000;

    public Cliente() {
        try {
            Socket skCliente = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
            InputStream aux = skCliente.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream flujo = new DataInputStream(aux);
            System.out.println(flujo.readUTF());
            Scanner Gato = new Scanner(System.in);
            InetAddress receptor = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            DatagramSocket socketEmisor = new DatagramSocket();
            String mensaje = " ";
            System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje" + mensaje);
            Gato.next().getBytes();
            byte[] bufferEmisor = mensaje.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket datagramaEmisor = new DatagramPacket(bufferEmisor, bufferEmisor.length, receptor, 5000);
            socketEmisor.send(datagramaEmisor);

            skCliente.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Limite de Peticiones en el Servidor");
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el servidor:

```
package pracsocket1;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Servidor {

    static final int PUERTO = 5000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Servidor();
    }

    /*consultor */
    public Servidor() {
        try{
            ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
            System.out.println("Escucho en el puerto " + PUERTO);
            int numCli = 0;
            String nom =" "; 

            while (numCli<10) {
                numCli++;/* cuantos clientes se unen AL servidor*/
                Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept();
                System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente " + numCli);

                OutputStream aux = skCliente.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream flujo = new DataOutputStream(aux);
                flujo.writeUTF("Hola Cliente " + numCli);

                DatagramSocket socketReceptor=new DatagramSocket(5000);
                int tamanioBuffer=1000; 
                byte[] bufferReceptor=new byte[tamanioBuffer];
                DatagramPacket datagramaReceptor=new DatagramPacket(bufferReceptor, bufferReceptor.length);
                socketReceptor.receive(datagramaReceptor);
                int tamanioMensajeRecibido=datagramaReceptor.getLength();
                String mensajeRecibido=new String(datagramaReceptor.getData(), 0, tamanioMensajeRecibido);
                System.out.println("Mensaje de : " + mensajeRecibido);
                System.out.println("En la dirrección:" + datagramaReceptor.getAddress());
                System.out.println("En el puerto:" + datagramaReceptor.getPort());
                socketReceptor.close();
                skCliente.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola, Jeremy!

Al parecer **¡estás omitiendo el mensaje!**, y por esto no se envía a través el socket.

En la clase **Cliente**, justo en este bloque:

```
String mensaje = " ";
System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje" + mensaje);
Gato.next().getBytes();
byte[] bufferEmisor = mensaje.getBytes();
```

Estás declarando `String mensaje = " ";`, como una cadena de texto con un espacio vacío, luego obtienes los bytes que provienen del **Scanner** (que utilizas unas sentencias más atrás) justo aquí `Gato.next().getBytes();`, sin embargo, esta línea de código está siendo omitida por el compilador, puesto que no estás almacenado los bytes obtenidos por el **Scanner**, y por último, obtienes los bytes del **mensaje** (y según vimos, está vacío).

Para solucionarlo, solo cambia `mensajes.getBytes();` por `Gato.next().getbytes();` y listo. Ahí nos cuentas ;-).

PD: Ese bloque de código puedes dejarlo así:

```
System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje");
byte[] bufferEmisor = Gato.next().getBytes();
```

`String mensaje = " ";` puede ser eliminado si no lo vas a utilizar.

Aquí una evidencia:

En el cliente:

[image: img1]

En el servidor:

[image: img2]

EDIT:

Con respecto a los mensajes incompletos, esto se debe al utilizar el método `next()` del **Scanner**. Según la [documentación de Java para la clase Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), el método `next()`:

> Encuentra y retorna el siguiente "token" (cadena de caracteres con significado coherente) completo del escáner.

Es decir, sólo obtendrá la primera palabra (sin espacios) de lo que escribiste.

Para evitar eso, utiliza `nextLine()`, en vez de `next()` y quedaría algo así:

```
System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje");
byte[] bufferEmisor = Gato.nextLine().getBytes();
```

Evidencia en el cliente:

[image: img3]

En el servidor:

[image: img4]

Comment: ¡Wow! muchas gracias. Me funcionó, pero ahora no me deja enviar más mensajes y además los mensajes salen incompletos :c

Comment: Listo, @JeremyDoom, revisa el EDIT de la respuesta.

Comment: Con respecto a lo de "no me deja enviar más mensajes", eso es porque estás cerrando la conexión en el cliente. Si quieres dejarlo "en línea", eso creo que sería una pregunta aparte, puesto que tu pregunta sólo trataba sobre el porqué no se mostraba el mensaje ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, jaja.

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, recuerda marcarla. Saludos y suerte.